# Open Source Graph Drawing program supporting Planar graph testing?

Tags: linux, graph, graph-layout, graph-drawing, planar-graph

In graph theory, a planar graph is a graph that can be embedded in the plane, i.e., it can be drawn on the plane in such a way that its edges intersect only at their endpoints.

Their are many algorithms which exist for planar graph testing (i.e. determining if a given graph is Planar). The best ones are in O(n) where n is the number of vertices.

Which open source programs exist which support the following features:

- Can Draw Planar Graphs
- Support an O(n) Planar graph testing.
- Support variable node size.
- Support fixed drawing boundary region
- Are open source

Answer (score 6):

I have a few pointers for graph visualization methods:

1. [Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/) - original version is in Java and the newer stuff is flash.
2. [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)
3. [Networkx with matplotlib](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) - all in python
4. [Ubigraph](http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/) - for animated 3D visualization

Answer (score 2):

I've found this one useful for all kinds of 2D work..

http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html

It's java based so you should be able to run it anywhere you have a suitable jvm.

Answer (score 2):

[Graphanalyzer](http://grafoanalizator.unick-soft.ru/program/indexen.php)

From the site...
...

> Graphanalyzer is an environment for visualization of graphs.
>   Graphanalyzer provides abilities for creating, processing of graphs
>   and shows the results of visualization. Program supports oriented and
>   nonoriented graphs, weighted and non weighted graphs. Program includes
>   many algorithms for graph processing, from path finding to planar
>   checking. This program is an irreplaceable helper for solving tasks
>   occurring in the graph theory. Visualization of graph and algorithm.

...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest use build your own using boost-graph libraries. A good information can be found on Donald knuth home page. There are some softwares which I have not used very much. Graphthing is one of those. I do not think it'll meet your requirement. If you are a research guy, then I  personally recommend not to be inclined towards visualization of graphs.